# Stop application if db version is wrong

Tags: flyway

I have an web application that runs in JBoss and i use FlyWay in command line mode to migrate between database versions.
    I want integrate Flyway in to my application using Spring Framework and only stop the deployment in to the web server if the db version is wrong. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I **strongly recommend migrating the database on application startup** so a mismatch can never occur.

If this is not an option, you can implement custom logic to check the results of `Flyway.info()` against the desired version.